# Null object comparison in Mockjax causing exception in jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery, mockjax

I am attempting to send back stub data via the Mockjax library.  The practice is working out for the most part with one exception: the library fails when it tries to do a *null* comparison of the live and mock data.  The Mockjax code is below, the data being sent in is the same as the data in the code snippet.

The error occurs in jQuery (line 630 in my file) when it attempts to find the length of a null object inside of $.each.  The version of Mockjax is 1.5.2, the version of jQuery is 1.7.1.

```
    $.mockjax({
        url: "service/endpoint",
        data: {
            elementId : "207710",
            floorId : null
        },
        responseTime: 0,
        proxy: '../../07-29-13-all-true.json'
    });
```

Has anyone encountered this and what was your solution?  I send *null* in multiple service calls, so changing that code isn't a great solution at the time.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this was a bug in Mockjax, the fix is in testing now.  You can read more about the bug here: https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax/issues/106